# Существует ли полный учебник русского языка?

Tags: общие-вопросы, обучение

Я уже прочитал вот этот учебник: http://www.alleng.ru/d/rusl/rusl342.htm

Однако некоторые разделы, по-моему, написаны не очень хорошо –– есть смысл почитать какой-нибудь другой. Ввиду всего этого я хотел бы узнать, по каким учебникам занимались Вы. Упражнения, если что, не интересуют, то есть книга нужна без упражнений. :)

Знаете ли Вы какие-нибудь полные учебники, где написаны про все случаи, которые нужно знать для того, чтобы писать грамотно?

Если да, то прошу поделиться. Важно заметить, что этот вопрос содержит ответы (Ваши советы) на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большой список книг со ссылками для скачивания: **http://www.media-school.com.ua/p/blog-page_12.html**

Из них основные:

*по орфографии и пунктуации*

Валгина Н.С., Еськова Н.А., Лопатин В.В. и др. **Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации**. Полный академический справочник. - М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Розенталь Д. Э. **Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке.** – М.: Айрис-пресс, 2012.

Розенталь Д. Э. **Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация.** – М.: Оникс, 2002 (**самая полная книга о пунктуации**).

*по стилистике и культуре речи*

Книги Розенталя, Солганика, Голуб и Введенской

*словари*

Лопатин В. В., Лопатина Л. Е. **Слитно, раздельно или через дефис.** Орфографический словарь. – М.: Эксмо, 2012.

Лопатин В. В., Нечаева И. В., Чельцова Л. К. **Прописная или строчная?** Орфографический словарь. – М.: Эксмо, 2011.

Остроумова О. А., Фрамполь О. Д. **Трудности русской пунктуации**. **Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений**.** Опыт словаря-справочника. – М.: Изд-во СГУ, 2009.

**Русский орфографический словарь**: около 200 000 слов / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – Изд. 4-е, испр. и доп. – М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2013.

Comment: Где же можно скачать Остроумова О.А? Заинтересовало немного. Вы сами читали?

Comment: Зайдите на страницу http://www.media-school.com.ua/p/blog-page_12.html и рядом с названием книги увидите ссылку для скачивания. Я читала. Это самый полный словарь вводных слов на данный момент. Но есть один нюанс: там отражены случаи авторской пунктуации, на которые не нужно обращать внимания, а то запутаетесь. То есть на пометки "редко вводное", "вводное при желании автора" не реагируем. Обращаем внимание на "обычно вводное", "чаще вводное" и т.п.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что я не нашел эту книгу в этом списке вообще. Как скачивать книги с этого сайта, я знаю. А вот найти книгу мне не удалось. Подскажите, где она?

Comment: >Существует ли полный учебник русского языка?   
  
И Общая Теория Всего.

Comment: Раздел "Словари рус. яз.", 4-я книга сверху.

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя я находил и нахожу все, что необходимо для грамотного письма.

Comment: Неужели у него есть все? Не верится как-то.